# Ajax called increment times on each colorbox load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have a jquery function that calls a php file on click of button in colorbox. The issue is every time I open the colorbox the php file is call incremental no of times via colorbox.

Jquery Code:

```
$('.ajax').colorbox({
                onComplete:function(){

                    $.colorbox.resize();

                    $(document).on("click","#list_schemes",function(){

                        $.colorbox({
                            href:"./php_page.php,
                        });

                    }); 
                },
```

Html Code:

```
<button type="button" id="list_schemes">Activate Schemes</button> // this is in colorbox
```

Please help with the solution.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: Can you share more code? I've experienced similar issues before. It was because the event kept added to the button every time I clicked it.

Comment: What else part of code do you require? Please let me know I shall add it.

Comment: @JungryulChoi I have added more code please see if you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the click event every ajax call. The code below should run only once.

```
$(document).on("click","#list_schemes",function(){
    $.colorbox({
        href:"./php_page.php,
    });
});
```

Comment: But then how will I fire the click event every time the color box loads?